# Program to batch process, mirror file structure, rename .mp3 and .wav files

Tags: file-management

Ok, I have been searching for a way to do this for sometime - started trying to write the process even, and just flop in regards to my abilities :)

Here we go:

I'm a DJ - I use .MP3 for personal listening, .WAV for performances.

I get a song in .mp3 format, clean the file name to "Artist" - "Title", build ID3 tags using %artist% - %title%, then put a key in the comment of each .mp3.

[image: Looks like this]

Next, I convert the files to .WAV via a program which clips it out, volume levels it, pitch corrects, etc. (Note: .WAV files do not accept "Comments" in metadata).

Now I'm left with two folders, .MP3 and .WAV., with subfolders breaking my tracks down by genre. Over time, they have started to vary a bit due to the massive amount of files in each. Now, they are completely unmatched and hold no consistency to one another.

Problem 1: I would like to run a batch process to mirror the file structure, based upon file names, in both locations. (I've found programs to do this, but because both files are not .MP3, they do not work).

The next problem brings us back to the problem with .WAV metadata. I would like to rename the files to include the Mp3 comment before the filename. This would be something like "1A Sir Mixalot - Baby Got Back", and can be done using the program Mp3 tag quite easily.

Problem 2: Because .WAV files do not have comments in metadata, I cannot batch process them to include the keys before the file.

I see two possible ways to do this.

1. Have a program match the two files, pull the metadata from the .mp3, and transcribe the change to the filename in the .wav.
2. Have a program match the filenames, bulk process the .mp3s to include the key before the filename, then mirror the filename changes based upon the previous matched relationships.
   Any thoughts, ladies and gentlemen?

Comment: Sounds like a Python script. Do you have any scripting expirience?